# Why does assigning a pointer to be a dynamic object and an array works?

Tags: c++, dynamic

Well, first of all I want to know if the following is 'legal' or at least 'not evil'.

Second, I want to know what is happening internally to make it possible! it is amazing and quite strange, I know that a pointer may be perceived a an indirect way to access to an object by its memory address, so I suppose that is due to that, that a pointer can be redirected to point over both, dynamic objects and arrays even after its declaration and multiple assignments.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    size_t size;
    std::cout << "Enter a size for an array: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    /*Creating a pointer to a single dynamic string*/
    std::string *pointer = new std::string();

    pointer->append("Some text");

    std::cout << pointer << std::endl;

    delete pointer;
    pointer = NULL;

    /*setting it to be an array*/
    pointer = new std::string[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        pointer[i] = "Number :" + std::to_string(i);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << pointer[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Many thanks.

#### Note:

I tried to repeat this creating a template class with a lambda inside (using typedef) and it did not worked.

Comment: The shown code seems to be well-formed. As far as "what is happening internally" goes, this is mostly irrelevant at least until such time that you get a job to write your own C++ compiler and C++ library, at which point this becomes something that you need to understand. Suffice to say that your C++ compiler knows what it needs to do in order to make this happen, and as you progress learning C++, and improve your C++ knowledge, you will gain a better understanding of how things **must** happen; but in of itself that really doesn't mean much, on its own.

Comment: In both cases the pointer points to a single object; in the second case there are more objects of the same type in adjacent memory locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has defined behavior and works fine. There is no problem with it, except that you are leaking the last allocation, which is not really optimal (but legal). Add a `delete[] pointer;` at the end.

---

The array version of `new` doesn't return the newly created array or a pointer or reference to it. Instead it returns a pointer to the first element in the newly created array.

```
pointer = new std::string[size];
```

After this `pointer` will point to the first `std:.string` of the newly created `std::string[size]` array. Just looking at `pointer` you won't know whether the `std::string` that it points to is part of an array or not.

This is why you can reference both arrays and single objects through the same pointer type. The same works with automatic arrays, which decay to pointers to their first element when assigned to a pointer.

This is also why you as the programmer need to remember which pointer points to a single object allocated with `new` and which one points to an array allocated with `new[]` and how long that array is (because in the former case you need to delete it with `delete` and in the latter with `delete[]`).

In practice you should not use raw `new` like this for that reason (and others). Instead use containers like `std::vector` if you need dynamically-sized arrays and `std::unique_ptr` if you need dynamically allocated single objects (although there is also a `std::unique_ptr` version for arrays).